# dlib issue on window 10

Tags: python, cmake, dlib

pip install dlib

Error:

```
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.21.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for dlib, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: dlib
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'f:\python\rio python\project rio\face_mmod_env\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Rio\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-muznbbzz\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Rio\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-muznbbzz\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Rio\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4nvv4sbo\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'f:\python\rio python\project rio\face_mmod_env\include\site\python3.8\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\Rio\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-muznbbzz\dlib\
    Complete output (64 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\Rio\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-muznbbzz\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Rio\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-muznbbzz\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=f:\python\rio python\project rio\face_mmod_env\scripts\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\Rio\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-muznbbzz\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.8'
    -- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
    -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.19041.
    -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.27.29111.0
    -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.27.29111.0
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
    -- Detecting C compile features
    -- Detecting C compile features - done
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    -- Found PythonInterp: F:/Python/Rio Python/Project Rio/face_mmod_env/Scripts/python.exe (found version "3.8.2")
    CMake Error at C:/Users/Rio/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-muznbbzz/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/FindPythonLibsNew.cmake:124 (message):
      Python config failure: Python is 32-bit, chosen compiler is 64-bit
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      C:/Users/Rio/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-muznbbzz/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/pybind11Tools.cmake:16 (find_package)
      C:/Users/Rio/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-muznbbzz/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/CMakeLists.txt:33 (include)


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/Rio/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-muznbbzz/dlib/build/temp.win32-3.8/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Rio\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-muznbbzz\dlib\setup.py", line 223, in <module>
        setup(
      File "f:\python\rio python\project rio\face_mmod_env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Users\Rio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Users\Rio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\Rio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "f:\python\rio python\project rio\face_mmod_env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:\Users\Rio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Users\Rio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\Rio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Rio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Users\Rio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\Rio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Rio\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-muznbbzz\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\Rio\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-muznbbzz\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "C:\Users\Rio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\Rio\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-muznbbzz\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\Rio\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-muznbbzz\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=f:\\python\\rio python\\project rio\\face_mmod_env\\scripts\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\Rio\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-muznbbzz\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.8']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'f:\python\rio python\project rio\face_mmod_env\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Rio\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-muznbbzz\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Rio\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-muznbbzz\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Rio\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4nvv4sbo\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'f:\python\rio python\project rio\face_mmod_env\include\site\python3.8\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Steps that I followed:

1.Download and install cmake and set as system path for all user from "https://cmake.org/download/" this link

2.Installed visual studio 2019 and download component "c++ cmake tools for window"

3. Manually added environment variable path
4. run command "pip install cmake"
   success
5. pip install dlib
   error which I given above

I'm using window 10 64 bit

Comment: This seems to be the crux of the problem: `Python config failure: Python is 32-bit, chosen compiler is 64-bit`. Is there a 64-bit Python installed on your machine that you can use instead?

Comment: yeah it is set to 32 bit, normally on my terminal it's uses 64 bit, but some how in virtual environment it set to 32 bit, i tried to create new environment it's also run on 64 bit, but no idea why my current environment is in 32 bit.

so how to change my current environment to 64 bit i'm using vs code

Comment: thanks, I create new environment it auto set at 64 bit and it worked

Comment: Great! Please consider writing up an answer post, explaining what you changed and how it fixed the issue so others can benefit from your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new virtual environment with python 64 bit configuration

run command:

pip install cmake

pip install dlib

and it work

thank you @squareskittles